# How can retrieve the mandatory attributes of a Pydantic object?

Tags: python, pydantic

How to identify mandatory attributes in a Pydantic object.
In the following example, the method `mandatory_attributes` does it manually.
Is it possible to identify all mandatory attributes automatically?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    mandatory1: str = Field(description="mandatory")
    mandatory2: str = Field(description="mandatory")
    optional: str = Field(default="", description="optional")

    def mandatory_attributes(self):
        """Need fix this method, to identify mandatory attributes automatically."""
        return ["mandatory1", "mandatory2"]


obj = MyClass(mandatory1="a", mandatory2="b", optional="c")
result = obj.mandatory_attributes()
assert result == ["mandatory1", "mandatory2"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Pydantic 1.x:

```
def mandatory_attributes(pydantic_model):
    return [field.name for field in pydantic_model.__fields__.values() if field.required]

assert mandatory_attributes(MyClass) == ["mandatory1", "mandatory2"]
```

For Pydantic 2.x:

```
def mandatory_attributes(pydantic_model):
    return [name for name, field in pydantic_model.model_fields.items() if field.is_required()]

assert mandatory_attributes(MyClass) == ["mandatory1", "mandatory2"]
```